# non-fullscreen tableview in the nib

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, uiview

I want to make an app with a uiTableview that is a quarter of the size of the screen. I started the project with the Navigation-based Application. Now I want to change the table-view to not fill the whole screen, but haven't managed to do so. I searched the web for an answer but haven't been able to find a solution.

Am I on the right track if I put the tableview into another view in the 'RootViewController.xib'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put your `UITableView` inside another `UIView` and just make it the size you want. You can put another view below (or above) it or just leave it blank or do whatever you like (banners)?

If you're using a `UITableViewController`, that will not do. You can, however, keep the implementation code of your class and change the controller class to `UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`.

Don't forget to point the view of the controller to the `UIView` you created, instead directly to the `UITableView` object.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, but I don't understand. When I created the 'Navigation-based Application' I then got the interface for the RootViewController looking like this (I use Core-Date): "@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {" which I then changed to: "@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>{". I put the UITableView inside a new UIView in 'RootViewController.xib'. In the 'RootViewController.m' I have: UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;.

Comment: If you want to access the tableView in other methods that are not delegate methods, you'll need to create an IBOutlet for it. inside the declaration, put a `IBOutlet UITableView *tView;` and link it using the Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks again Sergio, I will try that as soon as I can! :)